# Finding area inside a region plot

Tags: plotting, regions

How to find the area inside the following region plot:

```
 RegionPlot[{1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2] <= y <= 
   1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2]}, {x, 0., 1}, {y, 0., 1}]
```

Comment: Easy - use `ImplicitRegion`:
```ImplicitRegion[
  1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2] <= y <= 
    1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2] && 0 < x < 1 && 
   0 < y < 1, {x, y}] // Area``` returns the result `1 - Pi/2 + Log[2]` - [please read the docs for `ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

Comment: @flinty surprisingly if I define R as your implicit region and RegionPlot it it works, but If I replace 0 <  by 0.< it hangs: Mathematica 12.3  on MacOS

Comment: @chris on Windows 10 Mathematica 12.3.1 it returns 0.122351 with that change, so its either something specific to MacOS or it was fixed in the 12.3.1 update.

Comment: @flinty `// Area` works, `// RegionPlot` hangs with `0. < x < 1 && 0. < y < 1` on 12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021).

Comment: After ~`1000` sec. it generated [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYdyx.png) plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Integrate[1, 
 {x, 2 (Sqrt[2] - 1), 1},
 {y, 1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2], 
  1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2]} ]
```

$$1-\frac{\pi }{2}+\log (2) \approx 0.122351$$

Incidentally, you can quickly compute the limits on this integral by:

```
CylindricalDecomposition[
(1/2 - 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2] <= y <= 
 1/2 + 1/2 Sqrt[(-4 + 4 x + x^2)/x^2] 
 \[And] x < 1), {x, y}]
```